# Access Objective-C property from Javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, hybrid-mobile-app

I am working on a hybrid application. I am trying to access a `NSString` property of Objective-C class from my HTML bundle.

Objective-C class:-

```
@interface WebViewDisplayerViewController : WebViewController<UIWebViewDelegate>
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *strURI;
@end
```

HTML code:-

```
.....
.....
baseUrlFromNative = ??????? /* How to access the 'strURI'property here? */
var hostnameFromURI = ourLocation.hostname;
baseurl = baseurl.replace(hostnameFromURI, baseUrlFromNative);
.....
.....
```

The `strURI` will be changing at runtime of the application.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for asking this question... I went to look up a method call, and it turns out the answer I was about to give is out of date.  It used to be the answer is 'you can't'; the closest you got was creating a javascript string containing the value of the variable.  Apprently JavaScriptCore is changing that.

Comment: I am aware of passing the control back to Objective-C code, and getting control from Objective-C in HTML. But this time I want to access a property.
It is possible in `Android`. :(